# How to make multiple lines using Line Chart in palantir-slate application

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-slate, palantir-for-ibm-cloudpak-for-data

How to make multiple lines using Line Chart in palantir-slate application?

I want to draw multiple lines in the same x axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can add multiple lines by clicking `Add Data` button on the bottom right part of the window, within the Chart configuration when editing slate.